# Word to describe the completion of a planned rail journey

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, british-english

I am a native English speaker with, what I consider to be, an excellent vocabulary but I recently ran into a problem whilst compiling my list of New Year's Resolutions.

One item on the list is to take my children aboard the West Highland Steam Train in Scotland however I really struggled to write it to a standard I was happy with.

Terms already considered

> Board the West Highland Steam Train

Indicates the achievement is complete once upon the train and does not consider the entire journey

> Complete the West Highland Rail Journey

Indicates some adversity to be overcome or a guiding part of the journey belongs to me

> Alight the West Highland Steam Train

Same criticism as 'board'

> Ride the West Highland Steam Train

Sounds close to surfer vernacular of Southern California

I know that we are into hair-splitting territory but what would be the most suitable phrasing of this sentence paying deference to the language of the United Kingdom?

Colloquial is fine.

Comment: I think "ride" is in fairly common use in the US for taking a train trip. And there's Duke Ellington's song, "Take the A Train." But I don't know if either is proper usage in the UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/travel/2000/mar/11/4) says, "You'll **travel** the West Highland Line", though that omits the important element of steam.

Answer (score 6):

Consider:

> Take a trip aboard the West Highland Steam Train

or

> Travel on the West Highland Steam Train.

Comment: Travel was the word I had centred on; thank you.  Take a trip works perfectly as well.  I have no idea why I was drawing such a blank on this one sentence.

Answer (score 2):

***Undertake the West Highland rail journey, in its entirety***.

Answer (score 2):

I would use

> Tour the west coast of Scotland aboard the West Highland Line steam train.

Comment: Tour works quite well.  TY.